# NYTPhotoViewer 5.0.8 not building under SPM

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

We're migrating from cocoapods to SPM. We deintegrated and have been adding packages. All good until [NYTPhotoViewer](https://github.com/nytimes/NYTPhotoViewer). No problems adding it...

[image]

But getting this when building...
[image]

The [NYTScalingImageView.m](https://github.com/nytimes/NYTPhotoViewer/blob/develop/NYTPhotoViewer/NYTScalingImageView.m) file looks fine to me. The @interface declaration is there above the @implementation. And ANIMATED_GIF_SUPPORT is set to 1. I'm not sure what's wrong.

I'm guessing that the probable cause is something the NYT needs to fix. But I am new to SPM so is there anything I could have missed or gotten wrong when adding the package? Any ideas?

Xcode 14.1 on macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SPM packaging of the latest version of NYTPhotoViewer is broken until PINRemoteImage releases a new version.

However, it works if you force to 5.0.6.

https://github.com/nytimes/NYTPhotoViewer/issues/344